# PHP Laravel Post action

Tags: laravel, post, methods

I have a form page for users informations update but my post function isn't working.I have defined a post method in the blade page and I show the page as a formaction post.This is my code;

```
    @extends('layouts.admin-master')
    @section('content')
        <form action="post">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAddress2">Ad Soyad</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" name="name" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAddress2">Şirket</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" name="company">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputAddress">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputAddress2">Telefon</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" name="phone">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="inputState">Üyelik Tipi</label>
                    <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                        <option selected>Seçenekler</option>
                        <option>Bronz Üyelik</option>
                        <option>Silver Üyelik</option>
                        <option>Gold Üyelik</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label class="radio-container m-r-55">Tedarikçi
                        <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="secim" value="tedarikci">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
          `enter code here`          <label class="radio-container">Alıcı
                        <input type="radio" name="secim" value="alici">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form action="{{route('form.add')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kaydet</button>
        </form>
        </form>
@endsection
```

Comment: have you defined your post method in the `Route file ie. Route::post('form`,...)`

Comment: Yes,I did.This my route; 
Route::post('/formadd','HomeController@formaddView')->name('form.add');                                                                                                        
I am getting now this error;
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::selleradd(), 0 passed and exactly 3 expected

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@extends('layouts.admin-master')
 @section('content')

    <form action="{{route('form.add')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress2">Ad Soyad</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" name="name" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAddress2">Şirket</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" name="company">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress2">Telefon</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" name="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Üyelik Tipi</label>
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                <option selected>Seçenekler</option>
                <option>Bronz Üyelik</option>
                <option>Silver Üyelik</option>
                <option>Gold Üyelik</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label class="radio-container m-r-55">Tedarikçi
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="secim" value="tedarikci">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
  `enter code here`          <label class="radio-container">Alıcı
                <input type="radio" name="secim" value="alici">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kaydet</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this line in your form and it should work :

```
{{csrf_field()}}
```

and make sure that your route address is correct too

Comment: Thanx,I did :) Its started

Comment: if any answer helped you please mark it as the best answer. so others would know this topic is closed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

u can add @csrf above the button

Comment: thanx I got it:)